# Spring @Cacheable Map a ResultList

Tags: java, spring, caching

The example in spring-guides for caching shows how to retrieve one element and store it the cache

```
@Override
@Cacheable("books")
public Book getByIsbn(String isbn) {
    simulateSlowService();
    return new Book(isbn, "Some book");
}
```

I would like to query the DB get the all the elements at once and then store them on startup (PostConstruct) as a reference cache.

```
    public Collection<Book> getAllBooks() {
    return this.entityManager.createNamedQuery(Book.all, Book.class).getResultList();
}
```

Can you store the Map directly? should I call the  getAllBooks() method ad use the @CachePut in a BookService.

Could someone give an example/ best practice?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to load @Cache on startup in spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27940704/how-to-load-cache-on-startup-in-spring)

Answer (score 0):

Exactly, use `@CachePut`in your service in order to preload the cache. Return values of methods annotated with `@CachePut` are always placed in the cache.