# How to call @Cachable on startup in spring boot using caffeine cache?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, caffeine

I want to get data from DB and store into cache on startup using caffeine cache. Whenever i want that data i need to fetch it from cache itself without calling DAO class

I'm new to cache.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27940704/how-to-load-cache-on-startup-in-spring

Comment: Hi Evgeni Dimitrov, Thanks valuable response. Now I'm able call @Cachable on startup.  
Now I have one more doubt! For retrieving cached values I'm using below function. Is this proper way? Sample code for Retrieve `
 private Map<String,Map<String, Object>> getDataFromCache (){
  Map<String, Map<String, Object>> cachedData = new HashMap<String, Map<String, Object>>();  
  ValueWrapper valueMapper = cm.getCache("SAMPLE_CACHE").get("Directories");  System.out.println(valueMapper.get());  
  return cachedData;
 }`