# How to add entire table to cache in spring

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, caching, caffeine

I have a very small table which is not updated frequently. 
I want to add this to cache such that it updates every day.
I am using spring and caffeine to implement this. 
I able to load a startup but don't how to refresh it. 
Please help.

```
@Bean
public CacheManager cacheManager() {

    SimpleCacheManager simpleCacheManager = new SimpleCacheManager();

    Cache stringStringCache = new CaffeineCache("name", Caffeine.newBuilder()
            .recordStats()
            .maximumSize(100)
            .expireAfterWrite(1, TimeUnit.DAYS)
            .build());

    simpleCacheManager.setCaches(Collections.singleton(stringStringCache));
    return simpleCacheManager;
}
```

I can simply  fetch all records from repository and put that in the cache using 
cache.put().
But how i refresh it again from table after specified time interval.

Comment: show your code and what is not working

Comment: @user7294900 added in desciption

Answer (score 0):

found the answer.
It loads the table on first call.
After that we just to read from cache from subsequent calls

```
@Cacheable("name")
@Override
public Map<String,String> findNameById() {
    log.info("db call");
    return IteratorUtils.toList(bookRepository
            .findAll()
            .iterator())
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Book::getId,Book::getName));
}
```