# How to run combined CompletableFutures asynchronously

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, java-8, completable-future

I want to load data on the application startup by calling different services which returns lists of different object types. Each service calls DAO class to read some data. So I have created individual `CompletableFuture` like:

```
CompletableFuture<List<DTO1> future1 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> service1.callMethod1());
CompletableFuture<List<DTO2> future2 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> service2.callMethod2());
CompletableFuture<List<DTO3> future3 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> service3.callMethod3());
```

and combined them like:

```
CompletableFuture<Void> combinedFuture = CompletableFuture.allOf(future1, future2, future3);
```

If I do something like:

```
combinedFuture.thenRunAsync(()->future1.join(), future2.join(), future3.join())
```

Then I am getting the compile time error. I am new to the Java 8 concurrency features such as `CompletableFuture`, I thought calling `thenRunAsync` will run each `future1,future2,future3` in different threads. Is it correct way to do it by calling `thenRunAsync`? If Yes, then how to remove that compile time error?

But if I do something like:

```
Stream.of(future1, future2, future3)
        .map(CompletableFuture::join)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

It is returning `List<? extends List<?>>` then It seems to work but should I call `.collect(Collectors.toList())` ? I am not concerned about this combined result as each of the individual method calls are already annotated with `@Cacheable` for caching purposes.
Also, If I do something like:

```
Stream.of(future1, future2, future3)
        .foreach(CompletableFuture::join);
```

will it run each `future1,future2,future3` in different threads? How can I run `future1,future2,future3` in 3 different threads?
Is there any correct way to run these three database calls asynchronously?

Comment: Do those service calls really need to be wrapped in a `CompletableFuture`?

Comment: @andrew-s No, originally those methods are returning `List<DTO>`. I have wrapped them `CompletableFuture` and combined them to make async calls, not sure if that's the correct way

Comment: To clarify: why not just `service1.callMethod1()` ? Why wrap in a `CompletableFuture`?  Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27940704/how-to-load-cache-on-startup-in-spring) will help too.

Comment: @andrew-s As I said, as per my limited knowledge I have wrapped them in `CompletableFuture` to call them on different thread and If I do `service1.callMethod1()` then it will be called on same thread.

Answer (score 4):

```
CompletableFuture<List<DTO1> future1 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> service1.callMethod1());
CompletableFuture<List<DTO2> future2 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> service2.callMethod2());
CompletableFuture<List<DTO3> future3 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> service3.callMethod3());
```

This code is already instructing all three futures to run on different threads (assuming that there are at least 3 threads in the [common pool](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html#commonPool())). Calling `join()` on one of them simply instructs the calling thread to block on completion of that task, and doesn't change the fact that the 3 calls are proceeding in parallel. All of your solutions that compile are reasonable.

Comment: But when calling `join` only for the purpose of waiting for the completion, `CompletableFuture.allOf(future1, future2, future3).join();` is simpler than the other approaches. And even `future1.join(); future2.join(); future3.join();` would do…